# Google Drive API for Chrome packaged app

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-realtime-api

I was following quick start example for getting oauth setup for my packaged app.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js

In order to get the client id, they put localhost port in redirect uri field, but since I am not dealing with any local server, what should I put in there to get the client id? I don't have any url set all I have done is created a manifest file, background file and loaded the unpacked extension to start with. My packaged app just needs Google Drive api to access files from it. I am just confused in getting the client id part. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what the [Chrome Identity API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app.identity.html#client_id) says, it is possible to get a client ID through the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). Choose installed application as the application type and Chrome application from the installed application type. Then enter the your application's ID from the Chrome extensions menu.